# EclipseIDE(2022-12): JVM shared library does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

When I downloaded Eclipse IDE (Version 2022-12) and actually tried to open it on MacOS Ventura 13.4(arm64), I got the image "The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/. /lib/server/libjvm.dylib"does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3I7.png)

I have looked at other sites to find the jvm home path and rewritten info.plst but still get the same error message as before.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcNmx.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Bfg.png)

I would be glad to know how to solve this problem.

thanks for the help

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Eclipse? Use the current 2023-06 and make sure the Eclipse and Java are both aarm64 or both x86_64

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.
I am a beginner and downloaded 2022 although it is an older version to get started with the textbook.
After some research I found that I downloaded the package including the Japanese plugin and perhaps there was a problem there.
I will use the latest official version.